# Inserting a List using Jdbc on M:N relationship

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am having trouble implimenting the Many to Many features with it

[image]

this is the `Matiere` Model that contain a List of `Professor` :

```
 public class Matiere implements Serializable{

        private static final long serialVersionUID =1L;
        private int idMatier;
        private String nomMatiere;
        private List<Professeur> professeurs;
        getter and setter ...
    }
```

my problem is how to use jdbc to insert in a association table `Matiere_professeur`

Comment: According to your code you use kind of ORM. Are you sure you need JDBC solution? for the JDBC approach you just remove all records from the matiere_professeur table and insert all the pairs idMatier+ids for all the professeurs list members